# Set timeout to Angular Reactive From Validation message ngIF

Tags: javascript, angular, settimeout, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

Hi I'm using Angular (4) and i have a custom validator and display it via an `ngIF`

```
inValid(fieldName: string) {
  return (
    this.form.get(fieldName).hasError('pattern') && 
    this.form.get(fieldName).dirty &&
    !this.required(fieldName)
  );
}
```

I want to delay the `return` response so that a user has time to type a couple of characters before an error (if any) message is displayed. `name` is the value of the field in question. i.e. firstName

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="inValid(fieldName)" class="error-message">
  Invalid
</div>
```

Ideally something like what is used on the email field at https://twitter.com/signup I don't want to use `.touched`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can delay response using rxjs operator debounceTime on a form control's valueChanges observable:

1. import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime'; in component.

2.In subscribe you can set a component level variable which holds the result of inValid function and in html need to bind this variable to div to toggle error message.

this.form.get("name").valueChanges.debounceTime(1000)
            .subscribe(data =>  this.error = this.inValid(data));

`<div *ngIf="isError" class="error-message">
    Invalid
    </div>`

Note :- you can also subscribe to valueChanges on form element level to write a common solution for all form fields. refer onValueChanged function in angular doc for details.

Comment: Today needs to be piped

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you'd go with an async validator. Here's an example.

Async validators need to be declared after any sync validators so:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', [], this.asyncValidator]
});
```

And here is how your async validator could look like, here I've just set two custom validators, one that checks field is not empty, other checking that the field has at least 4 characters:

```
asyncValidator(control: FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {
  const promise = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // empty
      if (control.value === '') {
        resolve({'req': true});
      }
      // length
      else if(control.value.length < 4) {
        resolve({'minl':true})
      }
      else {
        // valid
        resolve(null);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
  return promise;
}
```

and then your template could look like this:

```
<div *ngIf="!myForm.get('name').pristine">
  <small *ngIf="myForm.hasError('req', 'name')"> Required </small>
  <small *ngIf="myForm.hasError('minl', 'name')"> Min 4 chars </small>
</div>
```

So now with this validator, with the timeout, the error messages are displayed with a delay.